# Convert timestamp with specified offset for timezone with Date();

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, timezone-offset

I've been digging through as many things as I can find, and I can't seem to find what it is I am looking for, so I am coming to the conclusion that I either don't know what I am looking for or its not possible. Either way..

What I am trying to achieve is taking a timestamp example: `1373439600000` and a given offset of -12 to 12 (is that correct, as far as range goes?) so I can then take that timestamp above subtract from it accordingly, and pass that new timestamp to the `Date()` function so I can then manipulate it for human readable display.

The offset is two part, It is user specified in one instance while in the other it is going to default to the local `getTimezoneOffset()` if not specified. So trying to figure out how to take that range and work with that. To do everything accordingly.

Ideas? Am I even approaching this in a correct manor?

The timestamps I am working with are already UTC, not sure of that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

The JavaScript `Date` type has *many* problems, but one of its major quirks is that it only understands two time zones - UTC, or Local.  It uses UTC internally and in certain properties and functions like `.toUTCString()`, but otherwise it uses the local time zone.

Many browsers will *accept* an offset when parsing a `Date` from a string, but that will just be used to set the UTC time.  Anything on the way out will be converted back to the local time zone again.

Fortunately, there are some great libraries out there for working around these problems.  [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) is perfectly suited for this.  Here is an example of what you might be looking for:

```
moment(1373439600000).zone(8).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z")

//  output: "2013-07-09 23:00:00 -08:00"
```

Of course, you can format as needed, or pass in a more complex zone offset like `"+05:30"`.  And if you need to use an actual IANA time zone, there is the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) companion project, which you could do something like this:

```
moment(1373439600000).tz('America/New_York').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss Z")

//  output: "2013-07-10 03:00:00 -04:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `Date` object does not provide may facilities for working with timezones. If you have the offset though, you should be able to compute the offset in milliseconds. Then you can add (subtract?) that value to your timestamp and use it to construct the appropriate `Date`.

Does that help?

Comment: It does doesn't its the direction I am heading overall, and have been since I asked the question. My problem currently is caculating the offset to add/subtract respectively from the timestamp. right now when I use `getTimezoneOffset()` the value is `420` when returned, and I am trying to figure out how that applies? If at all to anything I want to do overall, and if it doesn't what should I do to take the given range and calculate a correct offset to use based on that.

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do, but according to the docs, `getTimezoneOffset()` returns the local timezone offset in minutes, so you would need to convert that to milliseconds and apply it accordingly to your timestamp.

Comment: Minutes, doh, I must have skimmed over that. What I am trying to do overall is take the range -12 through 12 and then I guess at this point multiply that by 60, then multiply that by 60000, to then add/subtract that from the current timestamp to display the time based in that range. Overall. We want it to display based on the timestamp provided in the users current time zone, but offer a user an offset so if they are communicating with someone in a different timezone they can switch it to sync up accordingly. However the UI is mostly handled by JavaScript, and its a large data set to recall